# Editing symbol diameter related to catchment area using uDig

Tags: symbology, sld

I have a table with column Catchment area (in km2), and I need to set symbol diameter based on that column. I need to get .sld file so I'm working with uDig.

I found out how to do it, but result is not acceptable because symbols are too big. There is not any normalization option in uDig or QGIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When scaling point symbols, it's good to scale them in a way that double value results in doubled symbol area (not diameter). Therefore, one has to use the square root of the value as a multiplicand.

While calculating square root, normalization can be applied at the same time e.g. using Field Calculator in QGIS.

The Field Calculator query would look like this. (Replace x with the biggest area value in your dataset.)

```
sqrt( area_field ) / sqrt( x )
```

You can then create [Attribute-based point](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/points.html#attribute-based-point) styles.